# Is there a site for ranking Caribbean Beaches?

Tags: beaches, caribbean

This is kind of a broad question, but is there a site that ranks beaches? I know there is a CNN article that has "The 100 Best Beaches in the World", but I didn't find it that great. Obviously its a very subjective list, but I'm gathering information for a trip and having a number rank associated with a beach could help.

A site like tripadvisor would be great, only not tripadvisor since I really dislike it.

Comment: I know you dislike tripadvisor, but they have very good ratings of beaches, hotels and other stuff based on users rate http://www.tripadvisor.com/TravelersChoice-Beaches-cTop-g147237

Comment: A fantastic surfing beach may be too dangerous for a family outing with small children, and one great for a university student looking to party will be awful for a retiree seeking solitude. It can't all be reduced to numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, see, the problem even with the CNN list, and indeed any list like this, is that beaches are subjective in terms of 'what is the best'.  Some like busy beaches with lots of attractive people, others like party beaches, others like palm tree quiet deserted beaches.

However, since your question asked about sites that have ranked the Caribbean beaches, yes, there are plenty, easily found by googling 'best Caribbean beaches'.

Examples:

- TripAdvisor Travellers' Choice (yes you don't like Tripadvisor, but it has a great list) - [Top 25 beaches - Caribbean](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/TravelersChoice-Beaches-cTop-g147237)
- Touropia has their list of [25 Best Caribbean Beaches](http://www.touropia.com/best-caribbean-beaches/)
- Conde Nast has compiled a list of the 10 [Prettiest Beaches in the Caribbean](http://www.cntraveler.com/daily-traveler/2014/01/most-beautiful-caribbean-beaches_slideshow_item0_1)
- and the Travel Channel has ranked their [Top 10 Caribbean beaches](http://www.travelchannel.com/interests/beaches/articles/top-10-caribbean-beaches) as well

I've tried to keep to just major publications, as opposed to smaller blogs' lists of beaches, but their opinions are many and arguably just as valid.